# QSqlQuery row affected result

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt, qsqlquery

```
SHA256 sha256;
std::string s = sha256(pass.toStdString());

QString myquery = "declare @identifier nvarchar(100) = NEWID()\
        declare @user_name nvarchar(50) = '"+user+"'\
        declare @pass_word nvarchar(100) = '"+QString::fromStdString(s)+"'\
        declare @hint nvarchar(50) = '"+hint+"'\
        if NOT exists(select * from user_table where (userid=@identifier or username = @user_name))\
        insert into user_table (username,password,password_salt,userid) values(@user_name,@pass_word,@hint,@identifier)";
qDebug()<<myquery;
openSqlConnection();
QSqlQuery q3;
q3.exec(myquery);
```

After executing this query, I should see result which will be `(1 row(s) affected)` if executed successfully.

If `username` already exists in the database, the result will be

> Command(s) completed successfully.

To see the result from the `select` I use `q3.next()`.

How do I know that my query has been executed successfully?

Comment: `q3.numRowsAffected()` will show how many rows affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I know that my query has been executed successfully?

You have a number of options here. You could check either:

- **The returned value** of [QSqlQuery::exec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#exec)

> Returns true and sets the query state to active if the query was successful; otherwise returns false.

for example:

```
if (!q3.exec(myquery))
    \\ show error
```

- **The status** of the query, i.e. [QSqlQuery::isActive](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#isActive)

> An active QSqlQuery is one that has been exec()'d successfully but not yet finished with.

for example:

```
q3.exec(myquery);

if (!q3.isActive())
    \\ show error
```

- **The type** of [QSqlQuery::lastError](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastError)

> QSqlError::NoError    0   No error occurred.

for example:

```
q3.exec(myquery);

if (q3.lastError().type() != QSqlError::NoError)
    \\ show error
```

---

If you pass the check (the one you have selected), you could process your query further, e.g. to see if the `username` already exists and how many rows have been affected.